# How to use the >> operator in OOP in C++

Tags: c++, oop, operators

I'm "translating" an imperative C++ program to an OOP C++ program and I have a simple question (apparently).

In the original program, I have the following code:

```
Song song = askSong();

if(songExists(song) == false)
{
        song.id = nextSong;
}
```

Where askSong() returns a song with the information that the user indicates.

In OOP, the equivalent function to askSong() is the operator >>:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream &, Song &song);
```

And the way I thought to put that in OOP was this:

```
Song song;
cin >> song;
cin.get();

if(songExists(song) == false)
{
    song.getId() = nextSong;
}
```

But when I try to compile I have the following error: l-value required as left operand of assignment

I'm sure it's easy to solve, but I do not know what's wrong.

Thank you for the help.

---

SOLVED: Someone discovered the error, and yeah, it was a foolishness: the solution is to use a set method and not a get method.

Thank you all guys! :)

Comment: at which line is the error ?

Comment: What's the declaration of `Song::getId()`?

Comment: In song.getId() = nextSong, but if I put song.getSinger() = whatever before the if, I get the error in that line. It seems that the way of calling the >> operator is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is not with `operator>>` but with the line: `song.getId() = nextSong;`. `getId()` seems to return an r-value (a r-value is a temporary value), then it is not possible to affect ̀`nextSong` to a temporary. Consider to write a `setId(..)` method, and call it.

Comment: note that the terms lvalue and rvalue refer to expressions, not to types. to understand lvalue, think about what can be on the *left* side of an assignment operator. that's lvalue (modulo C++ complications like `const`).

Comment: OMG how I didn't think that before? Thank you, that was the error.

Comment: also note that rvalue expressions of class type can be assigned to by default. so it's a bit complicated.